# ASP.net MVC call stored procedure which select custom columns

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a application with Asp.net mvc razar using sql server, I have a table with columns named `Fname, Mname, lname, dob`. I created a stored procedure which returns data with `FullName, Age` like

```
Select Fname + Mname + LName As FullName, spFunctionReturnAge(dob) As Age
From Customer
```

I imported and created a function for this stored procedure, but when I import the stored procedure in edmx design view, there no entity or module which has a FullName and an age column.

How do I add a module or return all rows from this stored procedure?

*My stored procedure has some calculation with returning rows so I can not use the View directly, It can be done only by using Stored Procedure*

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to pass in parameters for some reason try using a view instead of a stored procedure.

```
CREATE VIEW vwCustomer AS
SELECT Fname + Mname + LName As FullName, spFunctionReturnAge(dob) As Age 
FROM Customer
```

Most if not all programs that reference tables from SQL Server will recognize a view as if it was a table, however stored procedures are treated differently.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom entity class and map it to the select method in the designer to a function. in the designer you can also map insert update and delete functions as well if you so desire but the procedure is slightly different.

For the select method, see:
http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-select-stored-procedures/

For everything else (insert update and delete) see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx